# GitHub Actions secrets not injecting into Python environment variables

Tags: python, github, github-actions

I'm facing an unexpected issue with GitHub Actions where I'm unable to retrieve the values of secrets within my Python script. Despite correctly defining secrets in my GitHub repository and attempting to access them using `os.environ.get("SECRET_NAME")`, I'm only getting `None` in return. Here's how I'm setting environment variables in my GitHub Actions workflow:

here's my Python snippet:

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient
import os

try:

    user = os.environ.get("MONGO_USER")
    password = os.environ.get("MONGO_PASSWORD")
    host = os.environ.get("MONGO_HOST")
    dbname = os.environ.get("MONGO_DBNAME")
    collection_name = os.environ.get("MONGO_COLLECTION_NAME")
    app_name = os.environ.get("MONGO_APP_NAME")
    uri = f"mongodb+srv://{user}:{password}@{host}/{dbname}?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName={app_name}&tls=true"

    print(uri)
    client = MongoClient(uri)

    client.admin.command('ping')
    print("Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!")
    # Complétez cette liste avec les symboles réels
    symboles = ["MC.PA", "RMS.PA", "OR.PA", "CDI.PA", "TTE.PA", "AIR.PA", "SU.PA", "SAN.PA", "AI.PA", "EL.PA", "SAF.PA",
                "CS.PA", "DG.PA", "BNP.PA", "DSY.PA", "KER.PA",
                "BN.PA"]
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

main.yml

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:  # Permet le déclenchement manuel
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 9 * * *'  # Exécute tous les jours à 9h00 UTC

build:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: '3.x'
    - name: Update SSL Certificates
      run: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y ca-certificates

    - name: Update certifi
      run: pip install --upgrade certifi

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        pip install pymongo
        pip install yfinance
        # Ajoutez ici d'autres dépendances si nécessaire


    - name: Testing Secrets
      run: |
        echo "$MONGO_USER"
        echo "$MONGO_PASSWORD"
        echo "$MONGO_HOST"
        echo "$MONGO_DBNAME"
        echo "$MONGO_COLLECTION_NAME"
        echo "$MONGO_APP_NAME"
      env:
        MONGO_USER: ${{ secrets.MONGO_USER }}
        MONGO_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MONGO_PASSWORD }}
        MONGO_HOST: ${{ secrets.MONGO_HOST }}
        MONGO_DBNAME: ${{ secrets.MONGO_DBNAME }}
        MONGO_COLLECTION_NAME: ${{ secrets.MONGO_COLLECTION_NAME }}
        MONGO_APP_NAME: ${{ secrets.MONGO_APP_NAME }}

    - name: Execute update_data.py
      run: python API/update_data.py
```

data.py

```
import os
print("MONGO_USER:", os.environ.get("MONGO_USER"))
```

My variables
[image: my variables]

[image: My secrets]

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/work/bourses/bourses/API/update_data.py", line 19, in <module>
    client = MongoClient(uri)
MONGO_USER: None
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.8/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 771, in __init__
    res = uri_parser.parse_uri(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.8/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymongo/uri_parser.py", line 557, in parse_uri
    dns_resolver = _SrvResolver(fqdn, connect_timeout, srv_service_name, srv_max_hosts)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.8/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymongo/srv_resolver.py", line 81, in __init__
    raise ConfigurationError(_INVALID_HOST_MSG % (fqdn,))
pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: Invalid URI host: none is not a valid hostname for 'mongodb+srv://'. Did you mean to use 'mongodb://'?
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Despite these configurations, `user` ends up being `None`. Has anyone encountered this issue before? How can I ensure my Python script correctly accesses the secret values?

Comment: Please give a [mre]. I'd recommend taking the [tour] and reading [ask].

Comment: Works just fine for me. Are you sure the secret is defined secrets and not in variables for example?

Comment: Are you creating the secret under repository secrets or environment secrets?

Comment: Here i add screenshots for show you my secrets and variables

Comment: it's my result of print : mongodb+srv://None:None@None/None?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=ClusterBourse&tls=true

Comment: How it works fine for you @TeemuRisikko please :)

Comment: Meaning if I copy-paste your example build, have a repository secret `MONGO_USER` and do `os.environ.get("MONGO_USER")` in a python script, I don't get None.

Comment: now my snippet is more complete and main.yml too

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

If you had only tested your own previous minimal example, you would've spotted the problem.

Previously you had something like this:

```
    - name: Execute update_data.py
      env:
        MONGO_USER: ${{ secrets.MONGO_USER }}
      run: python API/update_data.py
```

which works without a problem.

Now your complete example is equivalent to this:

```
    - name: Testing Secrets
      run: |
        echo "$MONGO_USER"
      env:
        MONGO_USER: ${{ secrets.MONGO_USER }}

    - name: Execute update_data.py
      run: python API/update_data.py
```

If you provide `env` to only one step, it's only available for that step. Each block starting with `- name` (or more precisely, starting with `-`) is a new step.

### Solutions

#### Option 1: Move `env` to build level

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    env:
      MONGO_USER: ${{ secrets.MONGO_USER }}

    steps:
      ...
    - name: Execute update_data.py
      run: python API/update_data.py
```

#### Option 2: Move `env` to correct step

```
    steps:
      ...
    - name: Execute update_data.py
      env:
        MONGO_USER: ${{ secrets.MONGO_USER }}
      run: python API/update_data.py
```